# Return rows from RIGHT JOIN that do not have matches

Tags: t-sql, sybase

In a simple `RIGHT JOIN` statement:

```
select *
from SRC_TABLE
right join DEST_TABLE
on SRC_TABLE.COL = DEST_TABLE.COL
```

How do I only return rows from the DEST_TABLE that DID NOT have a match from the `RIGHT JOIN` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get better performance writing this as:

```
SELECT d.*
    FROM DEST_TABLE d
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                         FROM SRC_TABLE s
                         WHERE s.COL = d.COL)
```

Comment: Hi Joe. Could you please give a quick explanation as to why that would give better performance?

Comment: This blog is for LEFT JOINs (which your query could easily be rewritten as) and SQL Server (which is why I hedged my bet with "might" as I have no sybase experience), but it provides some good detail: [Left outer join vs NOT EXISTS](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/)

Answer (score 2):

You only lack condition to select only rows that did not have a match and in this case, this column is `NULL`.

```
select *
from SRC_TABLE
right join DEST_TABLE
on SRC_TABLE.COL = DEST_TABLE.COL
WHERE SRC_TABLE.COL IS NULL        -- ADD THIS LINE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from SRC_TABLE
right join DEST_TABLE
on SRC_TABLE.COL = DEST_TABLE.COL
where SRC_TABLE.COL IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

EXECEPT is another option

```
select DEST_TABLE.COL from DEST_TABLE
EXCEPT
select SRC_TABLE.COL  from SRC_TABLE
```